# Property or method "item" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: vue.js, vue-directives

The application throws me an error in the console. 
The property or method "logo" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option or for class-based components, by initializing the property

This is what HTML and script look like.

```html
<template id="items-template">
    <span class="items">
        <img v-if="logo.name" src="/images/name.png"/>
    </span>
</template>

@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Vue.component('items', {
            props: ['logo'],
            template: '#items-template'
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: There is no reference to `model` anywhere in your template, so I suspect you haven't shared the correct code with us

Comment: logo is instead of model

Comment: Are you passing `logo` to this component from parent component ? It needs to be available in order for the component to use it. Otherwise define logo inside the components data object. 
`<parent-component><items logo="logo"></items></parent-component>
`

Comment: @uranshishko how to define logo inside the components data object?

Comment: @Asix 
EDIT: it actually needs to be a function that returns an object:
Vue.component('items', {
            data: function() {
               return {
                  logo: {
                       name: 'someName'
                  }
               }
            }
            template: '#items-template'
});

Comment: Iam passing logo to this component but is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. And everything works fine just it shows me this error

Comment: @Asix could you show us code for parent component ?

Comment: I need somehow disable showing that html code until variables are defined, that's it. How to do that?

Comment: @Asix i think we need a little bit more context in order to help you. There seems to be nothing wrong with the code you have in your question. However we have no clue if your passing down data to that logo prop from any parent component, or where you're getting that data from to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how it should work:

```
<div id="app">
  <items :logo="logo"></items>
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="items-template">
    <div>
      <span class="items">
        <img v-if="logo.name" src="https://thumbs-prod.si-cdn.com/d4e3zqOM5KUq8m0m-AFVxuqa5ZM=/800x600/filters:no_upscale():focal(554x699:555x700)/https://public-media.si-cdn.com/filer/a4/04/a404c799-7118-459a-8de4-89e4a44b124f/img_1317.jpg"/>
      </span>
    </div>
</script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script>
var itemComponent = {
    template: "#items-template",
    props: {
    logo: Object
  } 
}

new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
      logo: {
        name: 'someName'
      }
    },
    components: {
      'items': itemComponent
    }
})
</script>
```

In this example, div#app is parent, and it passes down logo to items-component logo prop.